# How to change default value of object(decimal)

Tags: c#

Default value for decimal object is `0M` (with precision), i need to display it without precision if it's 0.00 then only'

Comment: Any sample input and output?

Comment: It's displaying 0.00 I want to display as 0 only. (ignore 'greater then' word  in question, i am unable to edit right now)

Comment: Use the format string "0.##" to omit any unnecessary decimal places. Use as many # symbols as decimal places you would otherwise like to display. Example: `decimal m = 1; Console.WriteLine(m.ToString("0.##"));`

Comment: Conversion in string won't assign it back to a decimal object

Comment: "It's displaying" - what's displaying? What does your code look like? You haven't given us any context for what you're doing at the moment.

Comment: You're not going to override the internal precision of the decimal. If this is anything other than a print format issue, please add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.ToString()` to format it while displaying - See the code below

```
decimal inputDecimal = 0.00M;
Console.WriteLine(inputDecimal.ToString("0")); // display 0
// if the input is 110.000 then output will be 110
```